# Explanation of some lines of code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like someone to explain to me those lines of code, please. It might be important to mention that this code is part of a display function.

```
if isa(obj,'PhArea')
    disp(t)
elseif isequal(get(0,'FormatSpacing'),'compact')
    disp([inputname(1) '='];
    disp(t);
else%that is format loose
    disp(' ')
    disp([inputname(1) ' =']);
    disp(' ');
    disp(t)
end
```

Comment: Please post the code into your question and don't attach a screenshot

Comment: The by all means best way to see what a piece of code does is to run it. Please have a look at the debugger, http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code just determines how to display the value of a variable `t` depending on the type of `t` as well as the current `format` settings.

```
% If this is a PhArea instance
if isa(t, 'PhArea)
    % Then just display it
    disp(t)

% If the user has enabled compact formatting (format compact)
elseif isequal(get(0, 'formatspacing'), 'compact')

    % Display the variable's name and an equal sign (no spaces)
    disp([inputname(1), '='])

    % Display the variable itself
    disp(t)

% Otherwise
else
    % Display an empty line
    disp(' ')

    % Display the variable's name and an equal sign (with space)
    disp([inputname(1), ' ='])

    % Display an empty line
    disp(' ')

    % Display the variable
    disp(t)
end
```

**Update**

The following line is the trickiest here.

```
isequal(get(0, 'formatspacing'), 'compact')
```

What this does is retrieves the current [format spacing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/format-output-in-command-window.html#bs4myfc). The `0` is the graphics [root object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) which is used to store information that applies to a given MATLAB session. When the user specifies that they want to use `'compact'` format spacing, this configuration is stored within the root object.

```
format loose
get(0, 'formatspacing')
%   loose

format compact
get(0, 'formatspacing')
%   compact
```

So by retrieving the current setting as a string, you can then compare it (using `isequal`) to `'compact'` to see if the user wants to use compact format spacing or not.

Comment: Thanks you so much but would you mind explaining this line to me a bit more isequal(get(0, 'formatspacing'), 'compact'). I don't get what the 0 stands for in there @Suever

Comment: @ChSafouane Added an explanation